# How to change image url after upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I simply created the Facebook posting section in react functional

[image]

after I upload a picture I want to preview it and its working fine check this:

[image]

after writing something on description and upload image when I click post button it creates post like This:

[image]

forget the profile picture its giving everything same but I want it to preview the original image so is there any way in JavaScript to change the local URL to some working URL so I can see image

[image]

I am a beginner in react so kindly give solution in JavaScript because image preview is also done with JS

I don't know if this can help you or not but this is the code everything is written in App.js file and its exporting in index.js

```js
function like(e){
    const element = e.target;
    element.classList.toggle('changeColor');
    const thumbsUp = e.target.childNodes[0];
    if(thumbsUp.className === 'far fa-thumbs-up'){
        thumbsUp.className = 'fas fa-thumbs-up';
    }
    else{
        thumbsUp.className = 'far fa-thumbs-up';
    }
}
var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    output.onload = function() {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(output.src)
    }
    console.log(output.src);
};

function App(){
    var count = 0;
    var obj = [];
    const Upload = ({profile}) => {
        var [postDetail, settingPostDetail] = React.useState('');
        var [postImage, setPostImage] = React.useState('');
        
        function postBtn (){
            var output = document.getElementById('output');
            var imageUrl = output.src;
            postImage = imageUrl;
            var setObj = {
                id : count,
                postDetail,
                postImage
            }
            count = count+1;
            obj.push(setObj);
            settingPostDetail('');
            setPostImage('');
        }
        return (
            <>
            <div className="uploadContent">
                <div className="comment">
                    <form id="commentForm">
                        <div>
                            <img src={profile}/>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Whats on your mind..." onChange={(e) => settingPostDetail(e.target.value)} />
                    </form>
                    <div className="image-preview">
                        <img id="output"/>  
                    </div>
                    <ul className="uploadIcons">
                        <li><i className="fas fa-video"></i>Live Video</li>
                        <li><i className="fas fa-file-image"></i><input type="file" className="custom-file-input"  accept="image/*" onChange={loadFile}/></li>
                        <li><i className="far fa-laugh"></i>Feeling / Activities</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className="postBtn">
                        <input type="button" value="post" onClick={postBtn}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <Post functionalPost={obj}/>
            </>
        )
    }
    function Post(props) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-lone-blocks
        return(
            <div className="major_container">
        {props.functionalPost.map((postDetails) => {
            let {id, postDetail, postImage} = postDetails;
        return (
            <div id={id} className="post">
            <div className="post_top_bar">
                <div>
                    <img src={props.profile}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Muhaymin</span>
                    <p>12-12-2020</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>{postDetail}</p>
                <img src={postImage}/>
            </div>
            <div className="emoji">
                <div className="bg_img"></div>
                <div className="bg_img"></div>
                <div className="bg_img"></div>
                <div className="bg_img"></div>
                <div className="bg_img"></div>
                <div className="bg_img"></div>
                <div className="bg_img"></div>
            </div>
            <div className="reactions">
                <button onClick={like}><i className="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>Like</button>
                <button><i className="far fa-comment-alt"></i>Comments</button>
                <button><i className="fas fa-share"></i>Share</button>
            </div>
            <div className="comment">
                <form id="commentForm">
                    <div>
                        <img src={props.profile}/>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Write a comment..."/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    })}
    </div>
    )
    }
    return(
        <div className="main_container">
            <Upload profile="https://scontent.fkhi2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/126435904_2740947029493468_1372746916749511118_o.jpg?_nc_cat=108&ccb=2&_nc_sid=09cbfe&_nc_ohc=eFGfxtrYKHQAX_XyVSw&_nc_ht=scontent.fkhi2-1.fna&oh=a019fbfa628a7885d3ae7483fa2d017d&oe=5FFFE5BB"/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
body{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #18191a;
}
/* upload post */
.uploadContent{
    background-color: #252525;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}
.uploadContent .comment #commentForm{
    margin-top: 0;
}
.uploadIcons{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 20px 0;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(95, 95, 95);
}
.image-preview{
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.image-preview img{
    width: 100%;
}
.uploadIcons li:nth-child(2){
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 150px;
}
.uploadIcons li{
    color: rgb(182, 182, 182);
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
.uploadIcons li:hover{
    background-color: #ffffff1a;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.custom-file-input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .custom-file-input::before {
    content: 'Photo Upload';
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    outline: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    outline: none;
  }
  .custom-file-input:focus{
      outline: none;
  }
  .custom-file-input:hover::before {
    outline: none;
  }
  .custom-file-input:active::before {
    outline: none;
  }
.uploadIcons li i{
    margin-right: 7px;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.uploadIcons li:first-child i{
    color: rgb(231, 56, 56);
}
.uploadIcons li:nth-child(2) i{
    color: rgb(29, 134, 29);
}
.uploadIcons li:nth-child(3) i{
    color: rgb(219, 176, 33);
}
.postBtn{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.postBtn input{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #3688ce;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.post{
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #252525;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px rgb(31 31 31 / 80%);
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}
.post .post_top_bar{
    margin: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.post .post_top_bar div:nth-child(1),
.comment #commentForm div{
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.comment #commentForm div{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.post .post_top_bar::after,
.comment #commentForm::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #028302;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    left: 32px;
    bottom: 1px;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.comment #commentForm::after{
    left: 26px;
}
.post .post_top_bar div img,
.comment #commentForm div img{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.post .post_top_bar{
    display: flex;
}
.post .post_top_bar div:nth-child(2){
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
.post .post_top_bar div:nth-child(2) span{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.post .post_top_bar div:nth-child(2) p{
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    color: rgb(187, 187, 187);
    font-size: 11px;
}
.post div:nth-child(2) img{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0 0;
}
.post .emoji{
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0 8px 20px;
}
.post .emoji .bg_img{
    background: url("Facebook-Reactions-2020.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 21px;
    height: 18px;
    text-align: center;
}
.post .emoji .bg_img:nth-child(1){
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.post .emoji .bg_img:nth-child(2){
    background-position: -21px 0;
}
.post .emoji .bg_img:nth-child(3){
    background-position: -42px 0;
}
.post .emoji .bg_img:nth-child(4){
    background-position: -63px 0;
}
.post .emoji .bg_img:nth-child(5){
    background-position: -84px 0;
}
.post .emoji .bg_img:nth-child(6){
    background-position: -105px 0;
}
.post .emoji .bg_img:nth-child(7){
    background-position: -127px 0;
}
.post .reactions{
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(95, 95, 95);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(95, 95, 95);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.post .reactions button{
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    margin: 4px 0 4px;
    font-weight: 600;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 4px 32px;
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
.post .reactions button i {
    margin-right: 6px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.post .reactions button:hover{
    background-color: #ffffff1a;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.post .reactions button.changeColor{
    color:rgb(32, 120, 244);
    transition: .2s ease-in-out;
}
.post .reactions button i.fas.fa-thumbs-up{
    animation-name: jump;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    z-index: 10;
}
.comment #commentForm{
    margin: 10px 20px 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.comment #commentForm div{
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.comment #commentForm input{
    width: 100%;
    background: #333333;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 39px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15px;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
}
@keyframes jump{
    0%{
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(1.4) rotate(-15deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you share some code sample?

Comment: you have to upload the image to the server and store it, perhaps using sharding or sha256 of file contents for the filename, then once stored pass back the filename/url to the uploaded image then replace into the src

Comment: URL.revokeObjectURL is destroying/closing your blob